Is Kilz 3 the Wrong Primer for Wood Stairs
I have a lot going on and just assumed it was a good idea to prime my 1939 wooden basement steps before painting.I used Kilz 3 because it was around. Getting ready to paint the treads with Sherwin Williams porch and floor paint. Now I find out that you shouldn't prime wood floors/stairs? Then I find out that Kilz 3 isn't recommended for floors. What are my options? Do I need to sand off all that thick primer?

I found the info about the specific primer , Kilz 3, on their website it says "not recommended for floors". I've also read conflicting information about using primers on wood when painting with porch and floor paint.

It depends on why it's not recommended. Avoiding liability if slippery? Poor wear qualities? Also, why did you put on a thick layer?

I called Kilz and apparently the information on the website for Kilz3 primer was incorrect. Odd thing is the same thing is written on the tech data sheet. "Not recommended for floors' But Kilz customer technical service said it was fine to use Kilz3 on stair treads.
I didn't put on an extra thick layer, it's just thick primer.
